# save information in textinput kivy python

Tags: python, button, kivy, save, textinput

how can I save information to textinput and have it stay there after exiting? using the button

I need to enter a value in the text field, click on the button, exit the application, log in and so that the value remains in the text field

Code proba.py:

```
from kivy.app import App
from kivy.uix.screenmanager import ScreenManager, Screen
from kivy.lang import Builder
class Monday(Screen):
    pass

class Manager(ScreenManager):
    pass

    kv = Builder.load_file("proba.kv")
class appApp(App):
    def build(self):
        return kv

if __name__ == "__main__":
    appApp().run()
```

Code proba.kv:

```
Manager:
    Monday:
<Monday>:
    name: "monday"
    FloatLayout:
        size: root.width, root.height
        canvas:
        TextInput:
            text: "anything"
            multiline: False
            pos: root.width * 2 / 20, root.height * 18 / 20
            size_hint: (.35, .055)
            font_size: 18


        Button:
            markup: True
            text: "save"
            background_normal: ''
            background_color: 0.3, 0.2, 1.0, 1
            bold: True
            font_size: 30
            size_hint: (.2, .1)
            pos: root.width * 65/100, root.height * 1 / 2
```

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.

Comment: please reconsider my problem

Answer (score 0):

The simplest way would be to store whatever you want in txt file and then just apply it after restart

.py

```
from kivy.app import App
from kivy.properties import StringProperty
from kivy.uix.screenmanager import ScreenManager, Screen
from kivy.lang import Builder


class Monday(Screen):
    # reading the txt file and sending to the text input window
    with open('readme.txt', 'r') as f:
        contents = f.readline()
    my_text = StringProperty(str(contents))
    print(contents)

class Manager(ScreenManager):
    pass

kv = Builder.load_file("proba.kv")

class appApp(App):
    def build(self):
        return kv

    # obj = your input text, saved to readme.txt
    def saved_if_button_pressed(self, obj):
        print(obj)
        with open('readme.txt', 'w') as f:
            f.write(obj)

if __name__ == "__main__":
    appApp().run()
```

.kv

```
Manager:
    Monday:
<Monday>:
    name: "monday"
    FloatLayout:
        size: root.width, root.height
        canvas:
        TextInput:
            # setting up id so text input can be read by button
            id: text_input
            text: root.my_text
            multiline: False
            pos: root.width * 2 / 20, root.height * 18 / 20
            size_hint: (.35, .055)
            font_size: 18


        Button:
            markup: True
            text: "save"
            background_normal: ''
            background_color: 0.3, 0.2, 1.0, 1
            bold: True
            font_size: 30
            size_hint: (.2, .1)
            pos: root.width * 65/100, root.height * 1 / 2

            # activating function when button is pressed + sending text input to the function
            on_press: app.saved_if_button_pressed(root.ids.text_input.text)
```